# I'm having trouble looping with a for statement - I keep receiving a value error

Tags: python-3.x, loops, yfinance

I am working on backtesting a basic strategy. I'm trying to use a for loop to add a column to a dataframe, and I'm trying to make the column's value equal to the previous capital amount times the days return. It keeps giving me a valueerror. Can someone please look at what I am doing wrong? I'm also open to helpful tips on how to structure my code better for it not to suck :)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import copy
import time
import datetime as dt

tickers = ["AAPL"]
startcap = 50000
shares = 50000/155

ohlcv_data = {} # directory with ohlc value for each stock            

# looping over tickers and creating a dataframe with close prices
for ticker in tickers:
    ohlcv_data[ticker] = yf.download(ticker,period="1mo",interval="5m")
    ohlcv_data[ticker].dropna(inplace=True,how="all")
 
tickers = ohlcv_data.keys() # redefine tickers variable after removing any tickers with corrupted data

#define ema Formula
def ema(DF,a=12,b=36):
    df = DF.copy()
    df["ma_fast"]=df["Adj Close"].ewm(span=a, min_periods=a).mean()
    df["ma_slow"]=df["Adj Close"].ewm(span=b, min_periods=b).mean()
    df["long/short"] = np.where((df["ma_fast"] > df["ma_slow"]),"Buy","")
    return df.loc[:,["ma_fast","ma_slow","long/short"]]

def periodreturn(DF):
    df = DF.copy()
    df = df.copy()
    df["periodreturn"] = (1+df["Adj Close"].pct_change())
    df["periodreturn"].apply(lambda x: float(x))
    return df.loc[:,["periodreturn"]]

for ticker in ohlcv_data:
    ohlcv_data[ticker][["ma_fast","ma_slow","long/short"]] = ema(ohlcv_data[ticker])
    ohlcv_data[ticker][["periodreturn"]] = periodreturn(ohlcv_data[ticker])
    
ohlcv_data[ticker]["periodreturn"].fillna(value=1,inplace=True)

ohlcv_data[ticker]["Capital"] = 50000

for x in range(1, len(ohlcv_data[ticker])):
    
    
    if ohlcv_data[ticker]["long/short"][x] == "Buy":
        ohlcv_data[ticker]["Capital"][x] = ohlcv_data[ticker]["Capital"][x-1] * ohlcv_data[ticker]["periodreturn"][x]
    
    else:
        ohlcv_data[ticker]["Capital"][x] = ohlcv_data[ticker]["Capital"][x-1]
```

```
:\Users\bbeaver\OneDrive - East West\Personal - Bryson Beaver\BB Trial.py:56: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  ohlcv_data[ticker]["Capital"][x] = ohlcv_data[ticker]["periodreturn"][x] * 50000
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\Anaconda3x\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:1085 in __setitem__
    self._set_with_engine(key, value)

  File ~\Anaconda3x\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:1146 in _set_with_engine
    loc = self.index.get_loc(key)

  File ~\Anaconda3x\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py:676 in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 1
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\OneDrive - East West\Personal - Bryson Beaver\BB Trial.py:56 in <module>
    ohlcv_data[ticker]["Capital"][x] = ohlcv_data[ticker]["periodreturn"][x] * 50000

  File ~\Anaconda3x\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:1101 in __setitem__
    self._mgr.setitem_inplace(key, value)

  File ~\Anaconda3x\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\base.py:188 in setitem_inplace
    value = np_can_hold_element(arr.dtype, value)

  File ~\Anaconda3x\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py:2228 in np_can_hold_element
    raise ValueError

ValueError
```

Comment: Please include the entire error trace in your question.  We can't even tell where the error is coming from.

Comment: I would think the first exception would be more important than the second one.  Why didn't you include that?

Comment: For us to determine if there is something we can help with, please add the lines around 676 in datetimes.py

Comment: The code in your question is only 51 lines long.  Which is line 56?